# Find out Current Directory during Visual Studio C++ Debug session

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, immediate-window

I'm debugging C++ native application on Visual Studio 2015.
After stopping on a breakpoint, I would like to know the *Current Directory*. (It could have changed during the execution before stopping on that breakpoint).

On .NET debugging [it is possible through the immediate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367732/finding-current-directory-during-visual-studio-debugging-session/1367787#1367787). This does not work when debugging C++ native application.

### Is there a way I could find out the Current Directory when debugging C++ native application?

To make it clear - I don't want to change and build my code again. I would like to find this out **in the debugger** (watch window, command/immediate window etc.)

Comment: The `$env` [pseudovariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx) in a watch window (for the nicer viewer) could help, although it's not a direct answer.

Comment: @bogdan from a brief pass over the environment variables presented in `$env`, I could not find anything that reveals the Current Directory.

Comment: It typically contains entries like `=C:=` at the very beginning, which contain the simulated per-drive current directories. Unfortunately, this only works reliably in a console app. Those entries can be slightly different (or not present at all) in non-console windows apps, depending on other things that the app is doing. That's why I don't consider this an answer, but I thought it was worth mentioning. Adding a pseudovariable for this could be a nice [suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) to make to the VS team.

Comment: @bogdan Good idea. I've added a [new suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10951806-add-a-new-pseudovariable-that-reflects-current-dir).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015 there is a "C# Interactive" Window.
You can use the C# command from .NET solution you presented to get the current directory while debugging Native project. 
    View -> Other Windows -> C# Interactive

If you don't see this option you might want to reinstall VS2015 with C#/.NET components. (I have selected all C# related components during the install.)

Comment: For me, this is capable of printing a working directory, but it's not actually the working directory of the process.